# Error : Assigning to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' from incompatible type 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Hai I am trying to display multiple annotations in mkmap. While am adding the coordinates it shows the error:"Assigning to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' from incompatible type 'id'". I know this is a simple prob, but I have searched many times and tried a lot but none works, my code is,

```
for(int i=0 ; i<coordinates.count ; i++)
    {
     MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
     point.coordinate =[coordinates objectAtIndex:i]; //here it shows the error
     point.title = @"title";
     [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    }
```

kindly advice me to solve this prob. Thank you...

Comment: can you show your coordinates array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not an Objective-C object, but a `struct`, it cannot be directly stored in an `NSArray` object, but rather it must be wrapped within an `NSValue` object.

Therefore the code to read co-ordinates from the array is *probably*:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
[[coordinates objectAtIndex:i] getValue:&coords];
point.coordinate = coords;
```

However to know for sure, I would need to see how the array was created.