# Sending CLLocationCoordinate2D to parameter of incompatible type my code in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Xcode. I am developing a vehicle tracking app for that I need to display more annotation points simultaneously. For this I need to store the coordinates in the array but it shows the error: `Sending CLLocationCoordinate2D to parameter of incompatible type`
my code is:

```
NSString *urlMapString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://logix.com/logix_webservice/mapvehiclelist.php?uid=20&format=json"];
NSURL *urlMap=[NSURL URLWithString:urlMapString];
NSData *dataMap=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlMap];
if(dataMap!=NULL){
   NSError *errorMap;
   NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSDictionary *jsonMap = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataMap options:kNilOptions error:&errorMap];
   NSArray *resultsMap = [jsonMap valueForKey:@"posts"];
   for(int count=1;count<resultsMap.count;count++)
      {
       NSDictionary *resMap = [[resultsMap objectAtIndex:count]valueForKey:@"post"];
       NSString *latOrgstring =[resMap valueForKey:@"latitude"];
       latitude=[latOrgstring doubleValue];
       NSString *longitudeString=[resMap valueForKey:@"longitude"];
       longitude=[longitudeString doubleValue];
       //Center
       CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
       center.latitude=latitude;
       center.longitude=longitude;
       [coordinates addObject:center]; //here it shows the error
      }
}
```

Kindly advice me to solve this problem.
Thank you...

Comment: This is the same basic issue as your previous question.

Comment: BTW - are you really using Xcode 4? Apple won't accept such an app so if you plan to send your app to Apple, you must use Xcode 5. And with iOS 8 coming soon you should be working with Xcode 6 to support iOS 8.

Comment: @rmaddy kindly advice me to solve this, Thank you...

Comment: @rmaddy Now am planning to update my xcode....

Comment: Please put some effort into this after reviewing the answer to your last question. You can't write an app by getting others to do your work for you every time you get stuck. Try to solve this yourself first. Make an attempt. If you, after trying, you are still stuck, post what you tried.

Comment: ya sir I have tried a lot after that only I post this & for your advice I will try more thank you

Comment: Well you don't appear to be learning.  I told you in your previous question that those `struct`s could not be stored directly in an Objective-C collection, and you accepted the answer, however you didn't actually learn anything from it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925546/error-assigning-to-cllocationcoordinate2d-from-incompatible-type-id

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry am very new to objective-c i tried your code also for this error but i can't solve this..

Answer (score 2):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D center` isn't an object. You can store only objects in NSArray.
Use `CLLocation` for this.

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
```

Comment: Sorry could you please explain little brief about it? according the above code

Comment: @iBeginner CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C struct. If you want to store it in array you should use C array. But if you want to store location object in array you should convert it in to Obj C object. One of the options is to store CLLocationCoordinate2D in CLLocation object. Another way is to convert it to NSValue. You can see documentation for this methods here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/NSValue_MapKit_additions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you can only add objects to an `NSArray`.

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not an object -- it is a C struct.

The code you posted itself has one solution:
Create a `NSDictionary` with the latitude and longitude as key/value pairs and add the resulting dictionary object to the array.

Another approach is to create a `CLLocation` as shown in another answer.

A third idea is what @trojanfoe answered previously which is to wrap the struct in an `NSValue`.

**However**, note that [there is a convenient `NSValue` addition specifically for MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/NSValue_MapKit_additions/Reference/Reference.html) that adds these two useful helper methods:

- `valueWithMKCoordinate:` which returns an `NSValue` given a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`
- `MKCoordinateValue` which returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for the `NSValue`

For an example, see [How to store CLLocationCoordinate2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328173/how-to-store-cllocationcoordinate2d).

A final (at least in this answer) alternate approach which I would highly recommend instead of all the above is this...

- Why do you want to store *only* the coordinates in an array?
- Wouldn't you want to know what the coordinates are for (which vehicle, place, etc)?
- **Why not create a *custom class* that implements, say, the `MKAnnotation` protocol and has not only the coordinates (as a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property) but also *all the other information related to the coordinate*?**  The class would be a subclass of `NSObject<MKAnnotation>`.
- You could then conveniently access all the information in one place without using multiple arrays and trying to keep the objects in the same order so they all have the same index, etc.
- You could then directly add these objects to an `MKMapView` since they implement `MKAnnotation`.

Answer (score 1):

CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C struct, so you need to put it in NSValue container at first.

> An NSValue object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C
>   data item. It can hold any of the scalar types such as int, float, and
>   char, as well as pointers, structures, and object id references. Use
>   this class to work with such data types in collections (such as
>   NSArray and NSSet), key-value coding, and other APIs that require
>   Objective-C objects.

```
[coordinates addObject:[NSValue value:&coordinate withObjCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:new_coordinate]];
```

Or

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
[coordinates addObject: location];
```

Can't u directly  add coordinates to mapview that means Place MKAnnotation on Mapview, instead of taking coordinates to into array ?

SEE Below i commented with lines

```
for(int count=1;count<resultsMap.count;count++)
  {
   NSDictionary *resMap = [[resultsMap objectAtIndex:count]valueForKey:@"post"];
   NSString *latOrgstring =[resMap valueForKey:@"latitude"];
   latitude=[latOrgstring doubleValue];
   NSString *longitudeString=[resMap valueForKey:@"longitude"];
   longitude=[longitudeString doubleValue];
   //Center
   CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
   center.latitude=latitude;
   center.longitude=longitude;
    -----------------------------------------
  ////// Annotation is MKAnnotation Subclass
    Annotation * cartAnn = [Annotation new]; 
    cartAnn.coordinate = center; 
    [self.mapView addAnnotation: cartAnn];
  ----------------------------------------------------
  /////// [coordinates addObject:center]; //here it shows the error
  }
```