# What is the best variable type to store a coordinate in Xcode?

Tags: json, xcode, variables, coordinates

I'm working on an app that uses json to get coordinates from a website. So, my question is: what's the best variable type that I should use to store the coordinates from the website. I'm new to Xcode, and I don't really know the types of variables that are permitted.

Comment: The easy answer is CGPoint, but there are plenty of other ways (some efficient and some not so much) that you could go about this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Assuming you mean geographic coordinates with latitude and longitude, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926718/sending-cllocationcoordinate2d-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-my-code-in-xcod for additional ideas besides CLLocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) object to store that data. `CLLocation` will also give you helpful methods for determining the distance between two points, if you need to do that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks! So, this is what I'm using, but it won't let me use CLLocation for the json data.

`CLLocation *success = [jsonData[@"Latitude"] /*what goes here?*/];`

Comment: @JacobRichman: You have to parse out the latitude and longitude from the JSON data and convert it to a `CLLocationDegrees` value (a `double`), then call `-[CLLocation initWithLatitude:longitude]`.